# Compiling a program using Piston's image crate is slow

Tags: image, rust

I'm using Piston's image crate to read the dimensions and the color of each pixel of a JPEG image, but compiling the program is really slow.

Here is my example program:

```
extern crate image;

fn main() {
    let img = image::open("example.jpg");
}
```

Compiling this using **cargo build** or **cargo build --release** takes at least 13 seconds every time I've modified the source code!

Output of **rustc --version**: `rustc 1.7.0 (a5d1e7a59 2016-02-29)`

Output of **cargo --version**: `cargo 0.8.0-nightly (28a0cbb 2016-01-17)`

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Initial compile for image and its deps, 2:15.20elapsed, recompile time for just changing that simple lib.rs file, 0:22.58elapsed. Indeed not so good, and this is with a debug build! But I have an idea how to improve it..

Comment: [PR'd](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/image/pull/518) to fix that particular problem..

Comment: @bluss I hope you write an answer describing the problem and the fix in addition to your commit message ;-)

Comment: The PR was contribution enough I think. Besides, how can I answer a user that doesn't pose a question? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a local inner crate and place `extern crate image` inside  it. As long as the inner crate doesn't change, compilation of the root crate will be fast (2 secs).

**root/Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
wrapper = { path = "wrapper" }
```

**root/src/main.rs**

```
extern crate wrapper;

fn main() {
    let _img = wrapper::open();
}
```

**root/wrapper/Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
image = "*"
```

**root/wrapper/src/lib.rs**

```
extern crate image;

pub use image::{ImageResult, DynamicImage};

pub fn open() -> ImageResult<DynamicImage> {
    image::open("example.jpg")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We are continually working on improving the speed of the compiler, but some crates are slower to compile than others. I don't know much about this particular crate, but this just might be the case for now.